# Enclose open interval as $ x\to \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

Can I "close" an open interval $[0,\infty)$ as $x$ approaches infinity with some real number, if given that
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty }f(x)=f(0)$ ?

The final goal of the exercise is to prove that $f$ isn't one-to-one. So I thought I could use Weierstrass theorem to prove that a bounded interval (our new interval $[0,M]$ where $M$ as our "infinity" constant) has min/max so it will definitely will have $x_1,x_2$ that will $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for introduction to $\LaTeX$. Or [this](https://math-on-quora.surge.sh) but skip the introduction (because the introduction is different and does not apply to this site, rest is same).

Comment: @quasi youre right, i made a typo mistake. edited to equals to(not not equal)

Comment: Thank you! @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can do that as long as you also prove that the theorem holds in that context. I don't think that that's worth the trouble.

Even if you do that, I don't see how is it that you deduce from that there there are $x_1,x_2\in[0,\infty)$ such that $x_1\ne x_2$ and that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Anyway, if $f$ is constant, it is obvious that it is not injective. If there is some $x_0\in[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x_0)>f(0)$, then, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=f(0)$, if $x\gg0$ you have $f(x)<f(x_0)$. So, take some $x_1>x_0$ such that $f(x_1)<f(x_0)$. If $f(x_1)\geqslant f(0)$, there is some $x_2<x_0$ such that $f(x_2)=f(x_1)$. ANd if $f(x_1)<f(0)$, ther is some $x_2\in(x_0,x_1)$ such that $f(x_2)=f(0)$.

The case in which there is some $x_0\in[0,\infty)$ such that $f(x_0)<f(0)$ is similar.

Comment: Thank you very much, i already encountered in such an answer and thought that would be much complex but you made it look simple, and much shorter than my supposed way i guess.